# Macro to define color within SetCell

Tags: counters, expansion, tabularray

I'm using a macro to build a table dynamically, but I can't manage to color the cell with `SetCell` dynamically using a counter.

The colors are defined like `color@1`, `color@2`, ... and I'm using a counter to loop through the values to build the table content and color the cells.
This is a stripped version of the whole project I'm working on, so I can't change the syntax of the colors.

Here is a non-NWE :

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}       % Enhanced Picture
\usepackage{chngcntr}       % Change counters
\usepackage{etoolbox}       % Class manipulation
\usepackage{tabularray}     % New table style
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}     % Storing table data in macro
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}        % BEamer splitting tables

\definecolor{BXcolor}{rgb}{0.5, 0.0, 0.13}
\colorlet{BXcolorFG}{white}

% Color for the gradations
\definecolor{color@1}{RGB}{255, 221, 0}
\colorlet{color@2}{orange}
\definecolor{color@3}{RGB}{255, 0, 0}
\definecolor{color@4}{RGB}{35, 35, 35}
\colorlet{colorEmpty}{black!10}

% Colors for the text above the gradations
\colorlet{colorFG@}{cyan}
\colorlet{colorFG@1}{black}
\colorlet{colorFG@2}{black}
\colorlet{colorFG@3}{black}
\colorlet{colorFG@4}{white}

\newcount\tableLines
\newcounter{tableLine}


\newcommand\storeTableData[1]{
   \setcounter{tableLine}{0}%\the\numexpr4-#1}
   \def\tabledata{} \tableLines=4
   \loop
   \addto\tabledata{
       \stepcounter{tableLine}
       \def\tablelinecolor{\arabic{tableline}}
       test & \SetCell{color@\arabic{tableline}} \textcolor{color@\arabic{tableLine}}{Test} & Test \\
   }
   \advance \tableLines -1
   \ifnum \tableLines>0\relax
   \repeat
}%
   
\IgnoreSpacesOn
   \prgNewFunction \printTableData {} {
   % Simple function to return the content of the macro inside the table
   \prgReturn {\tlUse \tabledata}
   }
\IgnoreSpacesOff
   
\newcommand{\displayTable}[1]{%
   % Build the table data
   \storeTableData{#1}
   % Draw the table
   \begin{tblr}[evaluate=\printTableData]{Q[c,m]Q[c,m]X[l]}
       Test & Test & TEst \\
       \printTableData
   \end{tblr}
}


\begin{document}
    
\displayTable{test}

\end{document}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `color@\arabic {tableline}'.
```

This makes me thing that the macro `\arabic{tableline}` is not expanded to its content. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using (value of) counter `rownum` provided by `tabularray` in stead of counter `tableLine`:

```tex
   \addto\tabledata{%
      test &
      \SetCell{
         bg=color@\inteval{\arabic{rownum}-1},
         fg=colorFG@\inteval{\arabic{rownum}-1}
      }
      Test & Test \\
   }
```

[image]

It seems the `counter` library from `tabularray` package is not as powerful as expected.

Full example

```tex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}       % Enhanced Picture
\usepackage{chngcntr}       % Change counters
\usepackage{etoolbox}       % Class manipulation
\usepackage{tabularray}     % New table style
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}     % Storing table data in macro
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}        % BEamer splitting tables

\definecolor{BXcolor}{rgb}{0.5, 0.0, 0.13}
\colorlet{BXcolorFG}{white}

% Color for the gradations
\definecolor{color@1}{RGB}{255, 221, 0}
\colorlet{color@2}{orange}
\definecolor{color@3}{RGB}{255, 0, 0}
\definecolor{color@4}{RGB}{35, 35, 35}
\colorlet{colorEmpty}{black!10}

% Colors for the text above the gradations
\colorlet{colorFG@}{cyan}
\colorlet{colorFG@1}{black}
\colorlet{colorFG@2}{black}
\colorlet{colorFG@3}{black}
\colorlet{colorFG@4}{white}

\newcount\tableLines
\newcounter{tableLine}

\newcommand\storeTableData[1]{
   \setcounter{tableLine}{0}%\the\numexpr4-#1}
   \def\tabledata{} \tableLines=4
   \loop
   \addto\tabledata{%
      test &
      \SetCell{
         bg=color@\inteval{\arabic{rownum}-1},
         fg=colorFG@\inteval{\arabic{rownum}-1}
      }
      Test & Test \\
   }
   \advance \tableLines -1\relax
   \ifnum \tableLines>0\relax
   \repeat
}%
   
\IgnoreSpacesOn
   \prgNewFunction \printTableData {} {
   % Simple function to return the content of the macro inside the table
   \prgReturn {\tlUse \tabledata}
   }
\IgnoreSpacesOff
   
\newcommand{\displayTable}[1]{%
   % Build the table data
   \storeTableData{#1}
   % Draw the table
   \begin{tblr}[evaluate=\printTableData]{Q[c,m]Q[c,m]X[l]}
       Test & Test & TEst \\
       \printTableData
   \end{tblr}
}


\begin{document}
    
\displayTable{test}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

`\SetCell` in first cell of each row

```tex
   \addto\tabledata{%
      \SetCell{
         bg=color@\inteval{\arabic{rownum}-1},
         fg=colorFG@\inteval{\arabic{rownum}-1}
      }
      test &
      Test & Test \\
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, However, if the `SetCell` command has to be applied to the first column of the table, the coloring doesn't happen. How can I solve this ?

Comment: If you meant first (horizontal) "row", just provide colors `color@0` and `colorFG@0`, or use `\SetCell{bg=color@\arabic{rownum}, fg=colorFG@\arabic{rownum}}` and name cell colors from 1.

Comment: No I meant that if I want to color the first cell of the row (on the left), even if I move the SetCell command, it's not taken into account.

Comment: It works for me, see updated snippet.  Or maybe you could share your snippet in comment or if it's too long to fit in a comment, raise a follow-up question.

Comment: Simply add `\stepcounter{tableLine}` (required for my project) between `\addto\tabledata{%` and `\SetCell` and the coloring won't happen.

Comment: As a table command (a `tabularray` concept), `\SetCell` encountered at the beginning of a cell is executed before typesetting the table. But `\stepcounter` is never a table command, hence it's left as part of the cell content and executed when typesetting the table. I don't think in argument of `\SetCell` one can use the value of a counter updated by `\stepcounter`.  And I'm not sure if it's achievable by defining a new table command through `\NewTableCommand`. Perhaps you can post a follow-up question with description of the big picture of your project.